# Google Analytics GA4 outbound link tracking

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have GA4 setup on a film blog containing a gallery of films. Each film item is a link to watch the film on an external domains e.g. Netflix/Prime/YouTube etc.

I am trying to track Outbound Links in GA and see a list of the most clicked films.

I have the site setup to [measure outbound clicks](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13566436?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) automatically, but these don't give me the film titles of the items I'm trying to track.

The site is built on Notion and [Super](https://super.so) so I don't have access to the 'on page' HTML code so I can't add an `onClick` event to each film item.

However, each film is an element with a class and the film name as an ID. For example:

- `class="notion-collection-card" id="shawshank-redemption"`
- `class="notion-collection-card" id="the-matrix"`

**Question**

Is there a way to add some JS to the `<head>` or the `<body>` to track each outbound link targeting them using the `class` and then `id` for each link as the Event Label so they appear as a list of film titles in analytics?

***Reminder**: I can't add `onClick` events to the HTML directly. All I can do is add code to the `<head>`, `<footer>` or the top of the `<body>`.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by following this guide (below): GA4 Enhanced Measurement doesn't track the `link_text` `link_id` or `link_class` properties.

The guide explains how to setup a custom Outbound Click event in GTM and wire this up to capture these properties. Note: I had to move my setup to use a GTM container rather than the original gtag.js installation:

https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/missing-link-text-of-outbound-clicks-in-google-analytics-4/